# Using VBA to dynamically add ranges in a specific manner

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a table using excel/vba similar to the image posted.

[image]

Below is the code I have.

```
Dim nextRowAs Range
For i = 1 To N
  
    Set nextRow= ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    nextRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Set nextRow1= ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-3, 0)
     nextRow.Value = 0
      Set nextRow2= ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-2, 0)
     nextRow2.Value = 0
      Set nextRow3= ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0)
     nextRow3.Value = 0
```

I defined section 1 as a Named range and am copy and pasting it to the bottom, clearing the user input as I go.

What I need guidance on.

1. This code pastes each range to the bottom. I would like to paste it like the image, left to right first then top to bottom with 2 per row.

Comment: This is a pretty complex task with multiple parts - you will get better responses if you ask one specific question at a time.

Comment: Tried to separate it into 4 main questions so people can reply to whichever ones they want. All of them use the same image as context though and are kind of related to each other so figured I would post it in one thread as opposed to 4 separate ones to not spam threads (Already posted another one before this as well)

Comment: Welcome to SO; suggest to follow Tim 's comment. - Fyi It's a common reason to close a question if it *"currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."*

Comment: Also - why not try the approach you think will work?  It sounds quite reasonable to me.

Comment: Removed all additional questions. Was focusing on other questions, figured I would post it just in case someone had a better approach by the time I got to it as it does seem kind of messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this - looks a little complex maybe, but it's best to break your code into modular parts:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To 10
        CreateArea n
    Next n
End Sub

Sub CreateArea(areaNum As Long)
    With AreaRange(areaNum)
        AreaRange(1).Copy .Cells(1)
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = areaNum
        ResetArea .Cells
    End With
End Sub

Sub ResetArea(rngArea As Range)
    rngArea.Cells(2, 2).Resize(3, 1).ClearContents
End Sub

'return the range for supplied area number
Function AreaRange(areaNum As Long) As Range
    Const RNG1 As String = "E2:F6" 'first area
    Const PER_ROW As Long = 2      'two blocks per row
    Dim r1 As Range, rwOff As Long, colOff As Long, c As Range
    Set r1 = ActiveSheet.Range(RNG1) 'or set a specific sheet
    'calculate offsets for the area to be created (adding 1 empy row/column between areas)
    rwOff = Application.Floor((areaNum - 1) / PER_ROW, 1) * (r1.Rows.Count + 1)
    colOff = ((areaNum - 1) Mod PER_ROW) * (r1.Columns.Count + 1)
    Set AreaRange = r1.Offset(rwOff, colOff) 'return the offset range
End Function
```